# Creating a Webhook in a Yii2 API to automatically sent a response at a particular endpoint to frontend for realtime actions

Tags: php, yii2, webhooks

I am setting up my Yii2 API to use Webhooks and automatically sent responses through particular endpoints when certain actions happen on my api eg creation of a new user. I discovered that to make my application realtime, eg when a new user is created on the app, a notifcation is automatically sent to everyone using my application, I need my API to use webhooks at particular endpoints to sent that data to the frontend as soon as the action is triggered. At the frontend, I have to write a listener to listen to any response coming from that endpoint.

I am using Yii2 APi and ReactJs at the frontend. After doing some research on creating webhooks with Yii2, I came across degordian/yii2-webhooks https://packagist.org/packages/degordian/yii2-webhooks.

I have followed the tutorial and I have successfully installed the package and run the migrate which creates two tables in my DB. Now, I have tried running http://localhost/project/api/web/index.php/webhooks?r=/webhooks/create and I get an error

**Return value of degordian\webhooks\Module::validateWebhookClass() must be an instance of degordian\webhooks\void, none returned**

[image]

Here is the code related to webhooks in config/main.php

```
 'bootstrap' => ['log',  'webhooks'],
'modules' => [
        'v1' => [
            'basePath' => '@app/modules/v1',
            'class' => 'api\modules\v1\Module',
        ],
        'webhooks' => [
            'class' => 'degordian\webhooks\Module',
            'eventDispatcherComponentClass' => 'app\components\MyDispatcher',
        ],
],
```

I do not know what I am missing in this process . Please any ideas or better solutions to my problems will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have php <7.1 where were introduced new type hint `void`.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php

Just upgrade it to 7.1 or newer.

P.S. I've create a patch with minimal PHP version required https://github.com/degordian/yii2-webhooks/pull/7#pullrequestreview-219301604